# How to update the affiliation and attribute of member using fabric node

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-chaincode

I have fabric network setup with 2 organisation and 2 fabric ca, I have register and enrolled the user.

```
 1. How i can update the affiliation of user, I am trying to call the getCaName from node js and reenroll its doest not work.

 2. How to change the attribute of user using fabric node .

 3. How to revoke the certificate.
```

Comment: Try to avoid asking too many questions in one question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@fama

you can use my below snippet

```
let adminUserObj = await client.setUserContext({
  username: admins.username,
  password: admins.secret
});

let caClient = client.getCertificateAuthority();

let affiliationService = caClient.newAffiliationService();
// Check if organization exists
let registeredAffiliations = await affiliationService.getAll(adminUserObj);
if (!registeredAffiliations.result.affiliations.some(x => x.name == userOrg.toLowerCase())) {
  let affiliation = userOrg.toLowerCase() + '.department1';
  await affiliationService.create({
    name: affiliation,
    force: true
  }, adminUserObj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/IdentityService.html#update__anchor
2. https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/IdentityService.html#update__anchor
3. https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/master/FabricCAClient.html#revoke__anchor

Reenroll after the update: [https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/master/FabricCAClient.html#reenroll__anchor](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/master/FabricCAClient.html#enroll__anchor)

Comment: do i need to use the chaincode to query this and update using above methods ?

Comment: That's a Node SDK client feature, not chaincode. A chaincode does not do this, it works in its channel context. Maybe you should stop and clarify Fabric concepts before continuing developing. There is a los of content online.

Comment: You can also do it through fabric-ca-client command (https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#fabric-ca-client), but you were already talking about NodeJS in your question.

Answer (score 0):

client.setUserContext is no longer supported by HLF 2.2

you can make use of below snippet if you are working with HLF 2.2 and need to list down affiliations

```
const { Wallets } = require('fabric-network');
const FabricCAServices = require('fabric-ca-client');
let connectionProfile = yaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync('../gateway/connection-org2.yaml', 'utf8'));
// Create a new CA client for interacting with the CA.
const caInfo = connectionProfile.certificateAuthorities['ca.org2.example.com'];
const caTLSCACerts = caInfo.tlsCACerts.pem;
const ca = new FabricCAServices(caInfo.url, { trustedRoots: caTLSCACerts, verify: false }, caInfo.caName);
const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
const wallet = await Wallets.newFileSystemWallet(walletPath);
const provider = wallet.getProviderRegistry().getProvider(adminIdentity.type);
const adminUser = await provider.getUserContext(adminIdentity, 'admin');
let affiliationService = ca.newAffiliationService();
let registeredAffiliations = await affiliationService.getAll(adminUser);
console.dir(registeredAffiliations, { depth: null })
```

for documentation regarding other methods, visit [AffiliationService Class documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/AffiliationService.html)